# How much memory is used by GradleWrapperMain and GradleDaemon processes

Tags: gradle, gradlew

How much `memory` is used by `GradleWrapperMain` and `GradleDaemon` processes. I see 2 such processes being started for each of my application started with (`nohup ./gradlew bootRun`). This would help understand how much memory gets consumed by each App, as we are planning to run multiple Apps

```
jps

3494 GradleWrapperMain
2552 GradleWrapperMain
3530 GradleDaemon
10460 Jps
2588 GradleDaemon
```

Answer (score 0):

Command `jps` hints at a Linux platform or equivalent. There does not seem to be a gradle command to check memory.

Shell command [top](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) allows to watch memory use as other resources. The `m` flag might be the most relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the actual memory consume terminal on follow way:

```
programmname="firefox" # replace "firefox" by your programname
top | grep "$programmname"
```

The order of the value output is:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
```

Replace the "firefox" by the name of programm which you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Output the data like memory consume, of the program which you are interested in on terminal:

```
# Replace the xed by your programname
xed & pid=$!

# echo the pid of your program
echo $pid

# Start top and output the data like memory use
top -p $pid
```